# How to switch between gcc6 and gcc8 based on a variable in powershell

Tags: linux, bash, powershell

I am trying to switch between gcc-6 and gcc-8 based on a variable in a powershell script. I have both installed and my ~/.bashrc file is empty.

I have in `script.ps1`

```
$gccVersion = 'gcc8'

if ($gccVersion -eq 'gcc6'){
  'source /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/enable'
} else {
  'source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable'
}
```

However this does not work. It just sticks with the default gcc version no matter what variable I give it. What am I missing?

What is the easiest way to dynamically switch between gcc6 and gcc8 based on a variable?

Comment: [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in above comment, you've the invoke the given strings. I'd try to invoke them via the `&`-operator, like this:

```
$gccVersion = 'gcc8'

if ($gccVersion -eq 'gcc6'){
  & 'source /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/enable'
} else {
  & 'source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable'
}

# Check the last exit code and execution status
if ((-not $?) -or ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)) {
    Write-Error "Command failed"
}
```

You should also check the [LASTEXITCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#lastexitcode) and the [execution status of last operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#section-1).

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. When I try running the above I get the error:

`The term 'source /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/enable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Probably because I am writing this in powershell and it is trying to run `source`

Comment: In PowerShell you source files via the `.`-operator. But I'm not sure what happens if you're trying to source e.g. a bash script.

Answer (score -1):

Your `if` does not properly test the variable. Write it either as

```
if [ "$gccVersion" = gcc6 ]
```

or

```
if test $gccVersion" = gcc6
```

or

```
if [[ $gccVersion == gcc6 ]]
```